# ValueError: Cannot assign "<Airport: Name:Viru ....>": "Route.origin" must be a "Airport" instance

Tags: python, django

I a creating a Django app where my models (for now) include `Airport`, `Airline` and `Route`. Where a route is a model which has only three `ForeignKey` fields: `Route.airline`  should be an `Airline` instance while `Route.destination` and `Route.origin` should be `Airport` instances. Previously, I have filled my database with `Airport`s and `Airline`s
and now trying to run following migration but got a `ValueError`:

```
from django.db import migrations
from flights.aviation import list_routes
from flights.models import Airline, Airport

#this func returns list of dicts that include IATA and ICAO etc
routes = list_routes()


def add_routes(apps, schema_editor):
    # We can't import the  model directly as it may be a newer
    # version than this migration expects. We use the historical version.
    Route = apps.get_model('flights', 'Route')
    for route in routes:
        try:
            origin=Airport.objects.get(IATA=f"{route['dep_iata']}")
        except Airport.DoesNotExist:
            try:
                origin=Airport.objects.get(ICAO=f"{route['dep_icao']}")
            except Airport.DoesNotExist:
                continue
        try:
            destination=Airport.objects.get(IATA=f"{route['arr_iata']}")
        except Airport.DoesNotExist:
            try:
                destination=Airport.objects.get(ICAO=f"{route['arr_icao']}")
            except Airport.DoesNotExist:
                continue
        try:
            airline=Airline.objects.get(IATA=f"{route['airline_iata']}")
        except Airline.DoesNotExist:
            try:
                airline=Airline.objects.get(ICAO=f"{route['airline_icao']}")
            except Airline.DoesNotExist:
                continue
        new = Route()
        new.origin = origin
        new.destination = destination
        new.airline = airline
        new.save()
```

I was not expecting `ValueError: Cannot assign "<Airport: Name:Viru ....>": "Route.origin" must be a "Airport" instance.` because `Airport.objects.get` returns a single object that is an `Airport`. And error text is also not very explanatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are missing the equivalent of `Route = apps.get_model('flights', 'Route')`.

Hence the `Airport` model that you are calling is not the actual model.
I suggest adding the following below `Route = apps.get_model('flights', 'Route')`:

```py
Airport= apps.get_model('flights', 'Airport')
```

Comment: Got a similar error : ValueError: Cannot assign "<Airline: Com....>": "Route.airline" must be a "Airline" instance.

Comment: 3-4 lines above the error it was saying 00011_auto_20210220_1925.py", line 38, in add_routes  new.origin = origin

Comment: I think the problem lied somewhere else, I have changed my comment. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Glad I could help!